# Can we extract the others website analytics data using webmasters?

Tags: python, api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to extract the data of one website which is not mine. One of my friend have used Supermetrics(GUI) to do this. He is able to extract the data. I wanted to it by using terminal. I am using webmasters to do this. I have created Client ID and Secrete. I have used python code given for webmasters. But It always pops up URL directed is unmatched. 
Is it possible to do so?

````py
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys
from googleapiclient import sample_tools

# Declare command-line flags.
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
argparser.add_argument('property_uri', type=str,
                       help=('Site or app URI to query data for (including '
                             'trailing slash).'))
argparser.add_argument('start_date', type=str,
                       help=('Start date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
argparser.add_argument('end_date', type=str,
                       help=('End date of the requested date range in '
                             'YYYY-MM-DD format.'))


def main(argv):
  service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__, parents=[argparser],
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

  # First run a query to learn which dates we have data for. You should always
  # check which days in a date range have data before running your main query.
  # This query shows data for the entire range, grouped and sorted by day,
  # descending; any days without data will be missing from the results.
  request = {
      'startDate': flags.start_date,
      'endDate': flags.end_date,
      'dimensions': ['date']
  }
  response = execute_request(service, flags.property_uri, request)
  print_table(response, 'Available dates')


def execute_request(service, property_uri, request):
  """Executes a searchAnalytics.query request.
  Args:
    service: The webmasters service to use when executing the query.
    property_uri: The site or app URI to request data for.
    request: The request to be executed.
  Returns:
    An array of response rows.
  """
  return service.searchanalytics().query(
      siteUrl=property_uri, body=request).execute()


def print_table(response, title):
  """Prints out a response table.
  Each row contains key(s), clicks, impressions, CTR, and average position.
  Args:
    response: The server response to be printed as a table.
    title: The title of the table.
  """
  print('\n --' + title + ':')

  if 'rows' not in response:
    print('Empty response')
    return

  rows = response['rows']
  row_format = '{:<20}' + '{:>20}' * 4
  print(row_format.format('Keys', 'Clicks', 'Impressions', 'CTR', 'Position'))
  for row in rows:
    keys = ''
    # Keys are returned only if one or more dimensions are requested.
    if 'keys' in row:
      keys = u','.join(row['keys']).encode('utf-8').decode()
    print(row_format.format(
        keys, row['clicks'], row['impressions'], row['ctr'], row['position']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(sys.argv)```


```json
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "INSERT CLIENT ID HERE",
    "client_secret": "INSERT CLIENT SECRET HERE",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}```

I was expecting the table with results but Im getting url directed is not matched. I even tried 'localhost:8080' in the redirected url but it is not working
````